# Can openni_tracker calibration be avoided for successive users?

Tags: calibration, kinect, openi-tracker

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have a demo running on my robot that enables people to stand in front of the Kinect (which is the robot's head) and move their arms, then the robot moves its arms in a similar fashion.  (Thanks to Taylor Veltrop!) My question is that as one user moves away and another user takes their place and assumes the Psi pose, is there any way to avoid the calibration phase?  If it's necessary, then I guess I don't want to avoid it.  But this [earlier question](http://answers.ros.org/question/433/openni-skeleton-tracking-save-calibration-data) suggests that it is not necessary.  Since calibration some times takes a long time, it would be nice to skip it if possible.

Thanks!

patrick

http://www.pirobot.org

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9751/can-openni_tracker-calibration-be-avoided-for-successive-users?/) by [Pi Robot](https://answers.ros.org/users/30/pi-robot/) on ROS Answers with karma: 4046 on 2011-04-16

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As i mentioned, all works fine with saving the calibration of the first user and asign it to Ebers user in szene. It might Be necessary to decide weather a Skeleton is a plausible user or not. I use the torso quality and some other measurements (bone lengths) to decide weather there is a real user in scene...

You can use the Save/Load calibration data from the OpenNi API... Unfortunately i found no way to save it, so the First user has to calibrate with the PSI Pose...

---

Originally posted by [Thorsten](https://answers.ros.org/users/306/thorsten/) with karma: 61 on 2011-04-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [McMurdo](https://answers.ros.org/users/1973/mcmurdo/) on 2012-05-02**:
http://answers.ros.org/question/32373/autocalibration-of-any-pose-openni_tracker

@Thorsten, Can you please see if you can help me with this?